# limit return of list.where

Tags: c#, linq, list, windows-phone-7

i'd like to limit the return of this code:

```
Listx.AddRange(suggestions.Where(x => x.Contains(content)));
```

so, that only less than 7 items will be added. tried it like this way, but it doesnt feel right, and its pretty slow because listx containsup to 100 entrys.

```
Listx.AddRange(suggestions.Where(x => x.Contains(content)&&Listx.Count <= 6));
```

anybody got some hints to improve the performance of the second piece of code? It's used everytime the text-changed event of a textbox is fired, so it shouldn't delay the input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Enumerable.[Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) method to limit the results from any Linq query.

```
Listx.AddRange(suggestions.Where(x => x.Contains(content)).Take(6));
```

If I were you would get familiarised with the [101 Samples for Linq](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b), there you will find examples for every operation available on the Linq framework.

Comment: Doesn't this create a list of up to N, and then take up to 6 of N? It seems like just creating a new extension method that did both would be the way to go...

Comment: @willmel No, `Take` iterates through the first 6 elements of the `Where` expression, then stops. No temp list is created as this is just an `IEnumerable` chain.

Comment: But doesn't the where expression complete? (i.e. potentially grab more than 6 items)

Comment: @willmel No, the `Where` method will return an `IEnumerator` object, but won't iterate through the elements. It will be passed to `Take` which will control the whole expression: after 6 elements it just ends the iteration.

Comment: The whole Linq expression is passed into the underlining QueryProvider where it is translated to what ever query language used. For example in TSQL it would generate a script like this "select top 6 x where CHARINDEX(content, x) != 0" and so on. This is the beauty of Linq, it will not execute the a query unless you tell it to do so. if you had added a ".ToList().Take(6)" then the query would have executed (fetching all the items) and reduced on the client side with the take.

Comment: @dmportella This is true if `suggestions` is an `IQueryable`.